# jquery do multiple textarea

Tags: php, jquery

The concept of my script is

1. show a textarea.
2. when I start giving input to
   the textarea, it'll show the second
       textarea.
3. In the same way, when I start to
   input sometext in the second
   textarea,
   it'll show the other one and so on.

**html :**

```
<div id="question">
    Question 1:<br />
    <textarea rows="7" cols="72"></textarea>
</div>
```

**javascript :**

```
var num = 1;
$('#question').keyup(function(){
    num++;
    $('#question').append('
                    <br />Question '+num+':
                    <br /><textarea rows="7" cols="72">
                    </textarea>');
});
```

**the problem :**

when I input some word on `textarea1`, it shows `textarea2`.
but, when I input word again on `textarea1`, it will show a different textarea.

can any one please help me?
I don't get the idea for checking on my javascript.

Thank you

Comment: Curious who downvote this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, just a simple demo, http://jsfiddle.net/kCtHn/